# Link to products with the same image title (woocommerce)

Tags: images, links, title

I have products with a generic image. The image title is for example abc.png.
I would like to generate a link to all products with that image title.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter out products with same image name?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want to be able to make a link to all those products.